# Using address.call.value to send ether from contract to contract in 0.5.0 and above

Tags: contract-debugging, solidity-0.5.x

In Solidity v0.4.24 and below, I would send ether from contract to contract using the following code within a bigger function :

```
if (!_address.call.value(_ether)()){
                revert();
   }
```

After Solidity v0.5.0, this throws several errors on compile.

"TypeError: Wrong argument count for function call: 0 arguments given but expected 1. This function requires a single bytes argument. Use "" as argument to provide empty calldata."

"TypeError: Type tuple(bool,bytes memory) is not implicitly convertible to expected type bool."

"TypeError: Unary operator ! cannot be applied to type tuple(bool,bytes memory)"

Changing the previous code to:

```
if (!_address.call.value(_ether)("")){
                revert();
}
```

removes the first error, but the other two remain.

Changing the code to:

```
_address.call.value(_ether)("");
```

leaves the following warning. "Warning: Return value of low-level calls not used."

It seems to work in practice, but shows warnings and error symbols on Etherscan.

What could I do to remove these warnings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.7/050-breaking-changes.html#semantic-and-syntactic-changes:

> Functions `.call()`, `.delegatecall()` and `.staticcall()` now return `(bool, bytes memory)` to provide access to the return data. Change `bool success = otherContract.call("f")` to `(bool success, bytes memory data) = otherContract.call("f")`.

So in your, case you want this:

```
(bool success, bytes memory) = _address.call.value(_ether)("");
require(success); // if (!success) { revert(); } is fine too, just needlessly long.
```

Note that I've omitted a variable name for the second return value because you're not using it. If you cared about the return value, you'd want `(bool success, bytes memory data) = ...`.